# Drupal 7 form_alter broke ajax form with SQL IN array

Tags: ajax, drupal, drupal-7

I have next code in `form_alter` in my module:

```
$query = db_select( 'field_data_field_product_photos', 'p' );
$query->addField( 'p', 'entity_id', 'pid' );
$query->addField( 'f', 'uri', 'uri' );
$query->join('file_managed', 'f', 'p.field_product_photos_fid=f.fid' );
$query->condition('p.entity_id', $products_nids, 'IN' );
$query->condition('p.delta', 0, '=' );
$result = $query->execute();
```

But when in form clicks on other radio, ajax return error

[image]

`$products_nids` is just array like `array(10,14)`. And if place `array(10,14)` instead of `$products_nids` it will work normally. But `$products_nids` generates dynamically.

Does someone know what to do?

P.S. in error must be `field_data_field_product_photos`, not `field_revision_field_product_photos`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have a look at the SQL generated:

```
...WHERE (p.entity_id IN ())...
```

Quite simply, `$product_nids` is empty at the point you're passing it to the query, and that's producing invalid SQL as above. To avoid this, either fix whatever bug is stopping `$product_nids` from being populated correctly, or add some error checking:

```
if (!empty($product_nids)) {
  $query->condition('p.entity_id', $products_nids, 'IN' );
}
```

Comment: `$product_nids` doesn't empty - i check.
For example on some node `$product_nids == array(10, 14)`. If in query put `array(10, 14)` everything will work great.

Comment: Sorry, it is - look at the SQL produced, it can't lie

Comment: Well exactly, you've just proved my point :) If it works with a static array, then you know for definite that `$product_nids` is either an empty array, or isn't an array at all. Like I said, the SQL can't lie just look at the query string that's produced

Comment: My apologies, you were right - i recieve nid in bad way. And ajax callback couldn't recive it. That's why `$product_nids` were empty.
Thx for help)